# JSONObject is returning null

Tags: php, json, android-studio

I am trying to retrieve a vat number from my database to display when the user logs in. It was working fine and then all of a sudden stopped working and started to return the error:

> org.json.JSONException: Value null at vat of type
>   org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to int

and I'm unsure as to why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success =jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {

                            int vat = jsonResponse.getInt("vat");
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ChoiceSelectActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("username", username);
                            intent.putExtra("vat", vat);
                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                        }else{

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage ("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            };

            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
```

And here is the PHP file:

```
{<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("xxx.com", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM Name WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID,   $username,  $password,  $vat);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["password"] = $password;
    $response["vat"] = $vat;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: You are storing passwords in plain text. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: Have you stepped into the code to verify that the result is still returned?  You could put a watch on the jsonResponse to see what's inside it.  Sometimes API's change or go down or your network connection falters.

Answer (score 1):

even i faced the same problem. Try to sync gradle, click on the icon. Then the gradle will finish building, later on you can instant run your app

Comment: Thank you, but still no joy.

Comment: It didn't work, no. I' still trying to figure out what has gone wrong.